# Thunderbird cannot connect to my pop email account since upgrade from 68.x to 78.2.2 today

Tags: thunderbird, pop3, software-update

I've got a gmail connection which works fine, and a pop mail connection to my ISP. It says on the status line Connected to pop.rcn.com... but nothing ever happens, no new mails download.

Yet Thunderbird generally isn't hung up. I can go through old rcn emails, get new gmail emails, etc.  Just can't pull any new ones from rcn, and there are no error messages.  And I can send emails through that server, simply can't download them.  Verified, of course, with webmail access that there are new emails present for downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem while poking around in account settings.  The Server Security settings spontaneously changed to 'STARTTLS' and 'Normal Password' with the version upgrade.  Putting them back to 'None' and 'Password transmitted securely' restored access.

(Did not suffer this change last week when it upgraded to version 68.x, or on any previous upgrade.)